# Can't reach to an AWS EC2 instance website

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I just launched a instance on AWS and I'm trying to open the website. So I copy the Public IPv4 address and paste it on my page. But it always returns 
 `This site can’t be reached` 
 `35.78.183.239 took too long to respond.`
I've changed my firewall setting to access google chrome and set security groups HTTP, HTTPS. I can't figure out where the problem is. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a webserver server running on ec2, which is accepting connections? if yes? is it running on standard 80 or 443 port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify what webserver or AMI is on your EC2 instance.

You need to setup an AMI or manually install and setup a webserver for anything to show, otherwise the EC2 instance, while reachable, will not respond.

Make sure that ssh access is enabled and try ssh into the machine. If you can successfully login, then you know the instance is reachable and the problem is with your webserver software.  This will help you debug.

Answer (score 2):

What port is your application running on? When you enable HTTP and HTTPS it only allows ports 80 and 443 on the security group. This won't help if your application runs on a different port, so you'll need to add that to your security group to allow inbound traffic.